# how to download source code from code.google.com

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I need to download the source code of a project that is on code.google.com
I'm unable to execute the command given in the checkout section. How do I do it? This is the command to be executed in command prompt.

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/gpspeedo/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hg` is the mercurial command.  You'll need to have mercurial installed to do this.

Take a look [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) for information on mercurial

Comment: I got through with the tutorial. but i'm still not able to know the way the code can be generated...
WOuld you mind breaking down the steps to me...!

Comment: I've never used mercurial myself but it's similar to other version control systems... basically there's a server where the code is stored and you use the `hg clone` command to get a local copy of the code from the server.  You may be able to find an application that provides a GUI for mercurial, that might help if you find the command line a little daunting.